# How to create set with sum fields in duplicate elements?

Tags: mongodb

I have array of arrays with orders:

```
meals: [[{
          "name": "Fish",
          "servings": 20
        },
        {
          "name": "Pizza",
          "servings": 40
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "name": "Fish",
          "servings": 2
        },
        {
          "name": "Beef",
          "servings": 1
        }]]
```

Some times orders are duplicate for example fish. I want to create set with all elements and sum all servings.
I need to get result :

```
meals: [[{
              "name": "Fish",
              "servings": 22
            },
            {
              "name": "Pizza",
              "servings": 40
            },
            {
              "name": "Beef",
              "servings": 1
            }]]
```

Comment: Can't you sum them before saving to db?

Comment: I get information from db and generate a report about orders for users. In db orders save singly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `$unwind` twice (because nested array) and group by name adding serving with `$sum`.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$unwind": "$meals"
},
{
  "$unwind": "$meals"
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$meals.name",
    "servings": {
      "$sum": "$meals.servings"
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ggm9Hm5u3lj)